# Classification report in multi label

Tags: python, python-3.x, bert-language-model

I try to use BERT for multi-label tasks. My data set has 1000 data. I first use train_test_split to use 80% of my data set as a training set and 20% as a verification set. It is reasonable to say that the verification set is 200 data, but I When the classification_report is output, 409 pens are displayed in the support area. Is this normal? or how can I fix my code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix, classification_report
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

# Split the dataset
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Prepare the dataset for BERT
# tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

def encode_data(df):
    inputs = tokenizer(df["text"].tolist(), padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512, return_tensors="pt")
    labels = torch.tensor(df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]].values)
    return inputs.input_ids, inputs.attention_mask, labels

train_input_ids, train_attention_mask, train_labels = encode_data(train_df)
test_input_ids, test_attention_mask, test_labels = encode_data(test_df)

# Prepare the model
# model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=4)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=4)

# Train the model
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model.to(device)

train_dataset = TensorDataset(train_input_ids, train_attention_mask, train_labels)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
loss_fct = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

num_epochs = 3

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        input_ids, attention_mask, labels = batch

        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        logits = outputs.logits
        loss = loss_fct(logits, labels.float())

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

# Predict on the test set
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(test_input_ids.to(device), attention_mask=test_attention_mask.to(device))
    test_probs = torch.sigmoid(outputs.logits).cpu().numpy()
    test_preds = (test_probs > 0.5).astype(np.int32)

# Evaluate the performance
confusion_matrix = multilabel_confusion_matrix(test_labels, test_preds)
classification_report_str = classification_report(test_labels, test_preds, target_names=["A", "B", "C", "D"], zero_division=0)

print("Multilabel confusion matrix:")
print(confusion_matrix)
print("\nClassification report:")
print(classification_report_str)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzRq3.png)

I want to know the classification_report in the multi-label task